# pipe example between multiple child-process in C

Tags: c, pipe, fork, stdin, file-descriptor

When I working on pipe() function in C, I have confused a bit. My aim is to transfer data between child processes. I want each child to take an input from `fd[0]` and write to `fd[1]`. My code is here, but I couldnt obtain any result. Where is the mistake? How can I imagine pipe?

```
    int main()
    {

    char *arr = malloc(sizeof(int));
    int num;
    int fd[2];
    char *piping = malloc(10*sizeof(char));
    char *word = malloc(10*sizeof(char));

    while(1)
    {
        printf("enter the number of child: ");
        fflush(stdout);
        fgets(arr, 10, stdin);

        printf("enter word: ");
        fflush(stdout);
        fgets(word, 10, stdin);

        num = atoi(arr);

        pipe(fd);
        for(int i = 0; i < num; i++)
        {
                if(!fork())
                {
                        read(0, piping, 10);
                        if(i != 0)
                        {   
                            dup2(fd[0],0);
                        }
                        if(i != num-1)
                        {
                            dup2(fd[1],1);
                        }
                        write(1, piping, 10);
                }
                else
                    wait(0);
        }
    }   
    return 0;
   }
```

Comment: Why the dynamic allocation? I don't see any need for it, and where you don't need it, you should avoid it.

Comment: Possibly duplication of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43121331/calculations-in-childs-using-pipes ?

Comment: Also, consider using `scanf()` or `sscanf()` to read numbers from user input.

Comment: @JohnBollinger Maybe you're right, but it's not important. This is just example, I try to understand how it works and how I can implement it. So, I just wrote any number.

Comment: Additionally, the `dup2()` calls are doing very little for you.  They make me a bit suspicious about what you're actually trying to achieve (and if I'm guessing right then you're going about it the wrong way), but what your code actually does -- and what you say it should do -- it can do without duping any file descriptors.

Answer (score 2):

There is a ton wrong with this. Forget about all the pipe stuff for now and just look at the forking. The code looks like this:

```
for(int i = 0; i < num; i++)
{
    if (!fork())
    {
        // in child do something
    }
    else
        wait(0);
}
```

The parent goes into the loop, creates the first child and waits for it.

The first child goes into the second iteration of the loop, creates a child and waits for it

The first child's child goes into the third iteration of the loop, creates a child and waits for it.

and so on until we have an ancestor chain of num - 1 parents and children. The num - 1'th child simply exits, which means its parent will stop waiting and go on to the next iteration of the loop. It too will exit, so the num-2'th child will stop waiting, but it still has an iteration of the loop to go, so it creates another child and waits for it.

You are creating vastly more children then you probably want because you have forgotten that parent and child both carry on executing the same code after the fork. You probably want the if part of the if ... else to contain `exit(0);` as its last statement.

However, your problems are not over there. In the if part, you first try to read from stdin which means that all of your many child processes will block waiting on input from the terminal.

The dup stuff is currently pointless. Apart form the fact that you don't dup the read end of the pipe to stdin until after you have read stdin, when you fork you still have access to the pipe unless you call `exec` so why not use it directly. The child that writes can write directly to `fd[1]` and the child that reads can read directly from `fd[0]`.

Answer (score 1):

The immediate problem is that each child process waits to read something from its standard input (not the pipe) before it proceeds, and you're not feeding any input (or at least not enough for all the children).  Perhaps you meant to perform the `dup2()`, when you perform it at all, prior to the `read()`.

Although fixing that issue will probably let your program run to completion, the general strategy is flawed in at least these ways:

- the parent `wait()`s for each child before starting the next one.  That creates two kinds of issues

  - you don't have any actual concurrency.  What, then, was the point of forking?
  - if the children were writing more output to the pipe then they would be at risk of filling its buffer and therefore blocking.  That would produce a deadlock, because the buffer will be drained only by the next child, which is not started until its predecessor terminates.
- every pair of processes is using the same pipe for communication.  This only works at all because the parent serializes execution of the children (as discussed above).  Since such serialization has inherent problems, among other reasons, you ordinarily want each pipe to be dedicated to exactly one pair of processes.